# Calling a add_filter inside a Wordpress class

Tags: php, wordpress, class, woocommerce, add-filter

I´m trying to call this add_filter inside a Wordpress class. I followed all the rules, but for some reason, it doesn't work.

```
class WoocommerceController extends BaseController
{

function register(){
   add_filter('woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', array($this, 'woo_change_order_received_text', 10, 2 ));
    }
function woo_change_order_received_text( $str, $order ) {
    $new_str = $str . ' We have emailed the purchase receipt to you.';
    return $new_str;
   }
}
```

Comment: How are you trying execute this code?

Comment: @Dmitry what do mean by that? This class is initialized by another class. All the add_action functions work but add_filter never works

Comment: so you're editing this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are passing priority and parameters inside the array that's why its not working
add_filter('woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', array($this, 'woo_change_order_received_text'), 10, 2 )
write like this